# Converting integer to String

Tags: java, exception

i get Exception like this one:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

int idStation = Integer.parseInt((String) Stations.get(0));
```

This line is casting Exception. I did something like this many times and was good. "Stations" is a ArrayList.

Comment: `Stations.get(0)` is probably already an Integer

Comment: But if it weren't an integer: `Integer.parseInt(Stations.get(0).toString())`.

Comment: Yes, there is a integer, but Stations stores Object. your solution works, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `ArrayList<Object>`, you need to get the values as strings in order to call `Integer.parseInt`.

Casting to `String` doesn't actually change the object into a `String`: it just says to the compiler "trust me, I know this reference is really a `String`". So, it will only work at runtime if it is an instance of `String` already.

The `toString` method is the general way to get the string representation of an object. So, call this before calling `parseInt`:

```
Integer.parseInt(Stations.get(0).toString())
```

This is wasteful if `Stations.get(0)` is already an `Integer`; but in return for that wastefulness, you get generality. You *could* check if the object is a `Number`; you need to weigh the verbosity of this against the any efficiency improvement it might or might not offer:

```
Object station = Stations.get(0);
int idStation = (station instanceof Number) ?
                    ((Number) station).intValue() :
                    Integer.parseInt(station.toString();
```